# Rewriting an if check into a function

Tags: php

http://localhostr.com/files/V1ruKKj/capture.png

I want to rewrite all these ifs to something more manageable for lots of form fields.

I know it's not right but I want to rewrite it to something like this:

```
$fields = array(); 

function infcheck($var) 
{ 
if ( !empty( $var ) ) 
{ 
$fields[$var] = $var; 
} 

} 

infcheck( $_POST['streetname'] ); 
infcheck( $_POST['city'] ); 
infcheck( $_POST['state'] );
```

Basically when I run infcheck() I want the output to look like this:

Assuming $_POST['streetname'] is "Circle Street"

```
streetname => "circle street"
```

for a full example:

```
$fields = array(); 

infcheck( $_POST['streetname'] ); 
infcheck( $_POST['city'] ); 

//would be:

$fields = array(streetname => 'Circle Street', city => 'New York City');
```

I guess what I'm having trouble with is keeping the name of the form when `$_POST['formname']` is turned into a variable.

Comment: you may need to `global $fields;` in your function.

Comment: @jnpcl He most certainly **doesn't need `global`**. Nobody does.

Comment: @deceze: I meant in his current implementation.

Comment: @Tek What exactly is the goal? Currently you're just transferring all set variables from `$_POST` to another variable called `$fields`. Is that all you want to do?

Comment: @jnpcl Please don't advise the use of `global`, whatever the circumstances. :)

Comment: @deceze: Please don't pretend that it is not the way to fix the above code with the given implementation, when it is. This knee-jerk reaction against `global` is all well and good if you're going to provide a balanced argument, but please don't spread one-sided fear-mongering rhetoric to those who don't know any better.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not saying it's not a way to fix the above implementation. The OP is on the wrong track already with his solution, the use of `global` would just make it worse. There's virtually no situation where `global` is a good solution, so it shouldn't be advertised, *especially* to those who don't know better.

Comment: @deceze: You did not say all that. You just put misleading fear-mongering in bold. Also note that your hatred of global is still just your opinion.

Comment: @Tomalak Point taken. Next time I'll link to [other people's opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527) then.

Comment: @deceze: Yea, link to an answer that starts "Globals Are Evil" in big bold letters. How about a little balance? This is a programming community, not a propaganda campaign. We're not here to force people into specific viewpoints.

Comment: @Tomalak Then I'd be interested to hear your counter argument for why `global` would be a good solution here, as opposed to, say, my solution below.

Comment: @deceze: I don't think that it would be a better solution here. That does not mean I will go on a rampage pretending that it does not exist, and screaming at everybody not to use it under any circumstances, ever. Further, as an immediate fix to the current implementation, it's _completely_ valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're basically doing is this:

```
$fields = array_filter($_POST);
```

If you want to limit the `$fields` array to certain keys in a predetermined list and skip anything in the `$_POST` array that's not on that list, you can do something like this:

```
$whitelist = array('streetname', 'city', ...);
$fields = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($whitelist)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the array of values you want to pass through a foreach loop..

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

$fields[$key] = $value;

}
```